# Unable to ssh into ec2 instance: WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE! Permissions 0555 for '<key-name>.pem' are too open

Tags: ssh, lubuntu, amazon-ec2

After I created an ec2 instance, I tried to `ssh` into the port by using the private key, but even though I `chmod` the key down to `400`, I get this error.

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:/vagrant$ chmod 400 ./itmo-544-2019.pem
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:/vagrant$ ssh -i ./itmo-544-2019.pem ubuntu@<ip-address>
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0555 for './itmo-544-2019.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "./itmo-544-2019.pem": bad permissions
ubuntu@18.205.191.197: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I made sure the private key starts with

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and ends with

```
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I also tried `chmod 600 ./itmo-544-2019.pem`. But this didn't help either.

Any idea why?

Comment: Try `chmod 700 .` so the directory containing your private key is protected. Also check the owner of your private key file and the directory containing your private key (`/vagrant/`). Please post output of `ls -al .`

Comment: I also got same error but for me chmod 400 worked.